# Mockito - verify a double value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method called method1 that takes a double which is called on myManager
I am passing into this 65.888 * 60. When I try and verify this I get floating point problems. The verification fails. It expects  3953.28 but 3953.280029296875

```
verify(myManager, times(1)).method1(65.888 * 60d);
```

Is there anyway I can make this verify do a fuzzy check for floating point checking. Much like you do with assertEquals where you input a delta at the end.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but as in the api stated verify does not a check on the outcome. Verify does only: _Verifies certain behavior happened once_. So where is the code you are comparing the actual and the expected value?

Comment: It is mockito that is doing the comparing. It is verifying that the method is called with x but it is receiving y (due to floating point problem). The verifying is done somewhere in mockito code

Comment: Could you provide the whole test case. Because, normally there is a strong distinction. You assert a value (test state) and verify the invocation has happened (test interaction). You could also write `verify(myManager, times(1)).method1(anyDouble());`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could capture the value, e.g.

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Double> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Double.class)
...
verify(myManager).method1(captor.capture());
```

Then assert:

```
assertEquals(expected, captor.getValue(), delta)
```

Or, perhaps, use an argument matcher which does the assertion:

```
verify(myManager).method1(doubleThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Double>() 
{
    @Override 
    public boolean matches(final Object actual)
    {
        return Math.abs(expected - (Double) actual) <= delta;
    }
}));
```

### Update:

Instead of using either of the methods above, you could use [`AdditionalMatchers.eq(double, double)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#eq%28double,%20double%29) instead, e.g.:

```
verify(myManager).method1(AdditionalMatchers.eq(expected, delta));
```

Although use [`AdditonalMatchers`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html) matchers wisely, as per the documentation:

> AdditionalMatchers provides rarely used matchers, kept only for somewhat compatibility with EasyMock. Use additional matchers very judiciously because they may impact readability of a test. It is recommended to use matchers from Matchers and keep stubbing and verification simple.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. My actual code is a little more complicated as the method actually takes a string parameter as well. Using the doubleThat I now have to use ArgumentMatchers for each argument which is a pain. It works though so thanks! +1

Comment: I don't get why using `AdditonalMatchers` is not recommended. The second way is more readable in fact, so what's the point of discouraging people using it

Comment: I would argue that the `AdditionalMatchers.eq(expected, delta)` should be used over the standard floating-point equals. It is almost never a good idea to compare `double` or `float` directly. Even `JUnit`'s `assertEquals(expected,value)` is deprecated in favor of the comparison method using a `delta` value.

Answer (score 11):

There is a Hamcrest matcher that is perfect for this.

```
org.hamcrest.Matchers.closeTo(value, error)
```

So you could write something like

```
verify(myManager).method1(doubleThat(org.hamcrest.Matchers.closeTo(65.888 * 60, 0.001)));
```

Incidentally, you don't ever need to write `times(1)` in a Mockito `verify`, as this is the default type of `verify` that Mockito gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for me:

```
private class MockedClass {
    public void method1(double d) {}
}

@Test
public final void testMockito() {
    MockedClass d = mock(MockedClass.class);
    d.method1(3953.28);
    verify(d, times(1)).method1(65.888 * 60d);
}
```

Maybe you should instead call the method with anyDouble() or use following Matcher: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/IsCloseTo.html