# Mockito verify suffixes double Arguments for Method under test with 'd'

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm writing a unit test which should verify that a certain method is called. This method has two double arguments. What I'm doing in the test is this

```
Double lastAmount = 7.577283172873692;
Double currentAmount = 6.936618155701858;
     .
     .
     .
verify(calculator, times(1)).setToCurrent(lastAmount, currentAmount);
```

The test fails with the following Message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
calculator.setToCurrent(
    7.577283172873692d,
    6.936618155701858d
);
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335508/mockito-verify-a-double-value) but it doesn't help me with my problem. The thing is that the actual method call is done with double values WITHOUT 'd' suffix and Mockito checks for calls with a 'd' suffix.

I assume the question has an easy answer but I cannot get it. How can I get rid of the d suffix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito - verify a double value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335508/mockito-verify-a-double-value)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have seen this question before I added mine. But my problem is that the actual method call is done with two double values without 'd' suffix and Mockito checks for method call with 'd' suffix.

Comment: Please *show your research* when asking questions - see [ask].

Comment: The problem is not that you specify double values without `d` and that mockito expects them with `d`. The values in Java don't remember that, that is only compile time information on the type, not runtime.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But what can I do to verify that the method is called? Things like 'anyDouble()' or even 'anyObject()' don't work.

Comment: What happens when you write verify(calculator, times(1)).setToCurrent(Mockito.anyDouble(), Mockito.anyDouble()) ?

Comment: Wanted but not invoked: I think this means the method is not invoked at all. That is not a Double (with or without d) issue.